# Model Binding Null exception a View Component in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I use Asp.net core 2.1 and create View Component:

```
public class UploadFileViewComponent:ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(IFormFile formFile)
    {

        return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult) View("Default", formFile));
    }
}
```

and try to use this in razorpage:

```
@page
@using Mi24.Core.ViewMolde
@model Mi24.Web.Pages.Admin.Users.CreateUserModel
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Title"
}

    @await Component.InvokeAsync("UploadFile",new{ formFile=Model.CreateUserViewModel.AvatarFile });
```

but get error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

by adding this code to RazorPage above error solved:

```
[BindProperty]
    public CreateUserViewModel CreateUserViewModel { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        CreateUserViewModel=new CreateUserViewModel();
    }
```

on viewcomponent user select an images and by submit form OnPost method of razorpage fired but a catnt access to postedfile in Onpost:

```
public async void OnPostAsync()
    {
      string fileName=  CreateUserViewModel.AvatarFile.FileName;
    }
```

this error: System.NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part of the code in the demo I made ,check the difference

**CreateUserViewModel.cs**

```
 public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile AvatarFile { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the type of AvatarFile in CreateUserViewModel.cs must be consistent with the type of the object arguments in the InvokeAsync method of UploadFileViewComponent.

**Default.cshtml of the UploadFileViewComponent.cs**

```
@model RazorPage2_1Project.Models.CreateUserViewModel

<h2> Upload File</h2>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="AvatarFile" asp-for="AvatarFile"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Note : the value of `asp-for` and the `name` attribute of the input  should be the same to what you want get in the post method .